# How to create a table from a linked server into the local machine

Tags: sql, ssms, linked-server

I need to copy tables from a linked server onto my local machine. I am working in SQL management studio. The linked server is Oracle based. My end goal is to set up a stored proc that deletes a table if it exists and creates a new table in its place with refreshed data. This will be done for many tables as needed. The issue with the below code is that I get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

I am stuck at creating the table.

```
CREATE TABLE test AS

SELECT DUMMY 

FROM OPENQUERY (LServer, '

Select * 
from sourceT

');
```

The data in the dummy table is just one column with a single value "x". I have seen posts that suggest using a certain notation in naming the linked server table, like <server.database.schema.tablename> but this doesn't seem to work,even if I just run the select statement using the openquery. If I just run the select part in the script above, this does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE test AS
```

Is valid in Oracle but not SQL Server

You want

```
-- if the table already exists drop it
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;

-- now create a table and load into it
SELECT DUMMY 
INTO test
FROM OPENQUERY (LServer, '
Select * 
from sourceT')
```